# Find and return all duplicates of given user input in arrayList (Integers and Strings)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, duplicates, int

Having some beginner troubles.
I have an arrayList with several elements and I'm having problems trying to return a list of all duplicates.
The information I'm storing in the arrayList:

```
LogEntry(LocalDateTime date, String status, int id, String cod)

2018-10-23T12:05:22 DATA 325 6d33
2017-01-13T10:09:30 INFO 325 5f22
2018-05-10T18:55:30 INFO 111 6a23
2018-05-03T17:44:50 ERROR 325 5f22
2017-06-15T16:25:31 DATA 111 8472

ArrayList<LogEntry> logList = new ArrayList();
```

I tried using this to search for String entries:

```
    String logLevel;
    System.out.println("Search Log Level:\n(Info, Debug, Error)");
    logLevel = read.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    List<Integer> allIndexes
            = IntStream.range(0, logList.size()).boxed()
                    .filter(i -> logList.get(i).status.equals(logLevel))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // check duplicates      
    for (int i = 0; i < allIndexes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(logList.get(i).checkData());          
    }
```

But I'm having some mixed results (got wrong returns when running from another PC).

Trying to adapt to search for integers just isn't working:

```
private static void id_n() {
    int logid;
    System.out.println("ID:\n");
    logid = read.nextInt();

    List<Integer> allIndexes
            = IntStream.range(0, logList.size()).boxed()
                    .filter(i -> logList.get(i).id.equals(logid))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (int i = 0; i < allIndexes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(logList.get(i).checkData());
    }
```

}

So I'm already dreading trying to get a date range from this mess.

What I'm I doing wrong here? How can this be improved?
Thank you for any help.

Almost forgot, checkData is a function from my LogEntry Class:

```
public String checkData() {
            return " > " + this.date + " " + this.status + " " + this.id + " " + this.cod;
    }
```

**Solved**, thank you @JB Nizet and @Deadpool

**status**:

```
logList.stream().filter(i -> i.status.equals(logLevel)).forEach(j -> System.out.println(j.checkData()));
```

**id**:

```
logList.stream().filter(i -> i.id == logid).forEach(j -> System.out.println(j.checkData()));
```

For further manipulation of collected data I just sent it to a new arrayList.
**status**:

```
ArrayList<LogEntry> logLevels = new ArrayList();
logList.stream().filter(i -> i.status.equals(logLevel)).forEach(j -> logLevels.add(0, j));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Why do you create a list of indices, instead of a list of LogEntry? Why even make a list instead of simply printing from the stream directly? And what does "isn't working" mean, precisely? What is your concrete question?

Comment: I'm trying to get entire line when I find any duplicate on the arrayList, for instance when searching for ID: 111 I would get: 
2018-05-10T18:55:30 INFO 111 6a23 and 2017-06-15T16:25:31 DATA 111 8472. 
That's why I went with the indices, but from your comment that might not be a great idea...

Comment: What you call "the entire line" is "a LogEntry".

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `IntStream` is not a good idea, instead of that directly stream the `logList` object to get the duplicates

**Filtering based on Status and printing duplicate values**

```
logList.stream().filter(i->i.getStatus().equals(logLevel)).forEach(j->System.out.println(j.checkData());
```

**Filtering based on id and printing duplicate values**

```
logList.stream().filter(i->i.getId==logid).forEach(j->System.out.println(j.checkData());
```

Comment: Thank you, only had to make a small change to the code: `logList.stream().filter(i -> i.status.equals(logLevel)).forEach(j -> System.out.println(j.checkData()));`